# Price difference between buying a bike in Europe (Austria) vs USA?

Tags: single-speed, us, price, europe

I am moving to Vienna, Austria in two weeks.

My wife and I want to buy bikes before we leave, but I'm wondering if the hassle of trying to find great bikes on such short notice would be greater than just buying some when we get there.

My wife is looking for a town bike for

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: You'll probably have a better choice of town bikes over there.  Hard to tell about cost, but you've got to figure the cost of shipping the bikes (unless your employer is paying for it all).

Comment: To add to Daniel's comment about shipping -- there's lots of horror stories about damage incurred during shipping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would be in favor of waiting until you move. There is the possible problem of needing service work under warranty and the nearest dealer being some distance away. You must also factor in the shipping cost  along with the expense of disassembly and reassembly if you can't do it yourself. There is also no better way to start a good relationship with your local shop than by buying two bikes. The other advantage is being able to check out the terrain and see what type of bike you need.